# Auto Login in website using windows login details via javascript? How?

Tags: javascript

I want to write javascript in my application/website so it will auto login my website using windows login details. How can I achieve this using javascript? Browser can be IE or Chrome or any other Javascript codes but unable to fetch password of windows for authentication. All things tried in only Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Client-side JavaScript cannot do this (and it would be *awful* if any website you visited could read the password you use to login to Windows!)

Authenticating with Windows login details through a browser is, as far as I know, only possible via [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager).

You could write the server-side component of an implementation of NTLM in server-side JavaScript if you wished, but it would be more typical to use an out-of-the-box implementation such as the one built into [IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324276/how-to-configure-internet-information-services-web-authentication-in-w) or [this Apache module](http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/).

NTLM may require you to [configure your browser](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingFederate/Integrations/How-to-configure-supported-browsers-for-Kerberos-NTLM) to support it.

Comment: In general you're correct, but NTLM is *NOT* the answer. Windows Integrated Auth uses SPNEGO (Negotiate) which will try Kerberos first *then* NTLM. Kerberos is always preferred over NTLM.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with JavaScript alone, you need to do this with some server side solution such as Kerberos in combination with your Active Directory server (or use an older technique such as NTLM). I'm not sure if there are newer/better ways to achieve this than using Kerberos. 
Any solution will very very likely require configuration in your browser and not all browsers will support all approaches.

Some details can be found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/254813/why-use-kerberos-instead-of-ntlm-in-iis and https://www.roguelynn.com/words/explain-like-im-5-kerberos/